# Why removing a Security Group from a site , will also remove it from the underlying list and list items which have unique permissions

Tags: development, permissions, administration, configuration, site-settings

I faced this weird behavior inside my sharepoint on-premises 2013.

1. i have a sub-site which have a unique permission , and inside this sub-site i added a security group named "Network Members" and i grant it "Restricted interfaces for translate":-
   [image]
2. then inside this sub-site i have a list, which also have a unique permission. and inside this list i added the same group "Network Members", grant it a Read permission:-
   [image]
3. finally i have a list item, which i define to have a unique permission, and inside the list item i added the "Network Members" and grant it a Contribute permission as follow:-
   [image]

now i removed the "Network Members" group from the sub-site, as follow:-
[image]

But i have noted that the "Network members" group was also removed from the List and the related list items. so i am not sure if this is a bug. as when i add the security group to the sub-site it was not added to the list and list items, since each component have a unique permission. but why when i remove the security group from the sub-site it was removed from the list and list items.. now i can add back the security group to the list and the list items without having to add it first to the sub-site... so can anyone adivce how this is being handled?

Answer (score 2):

That behavior is intended.
With the final scenario you described (adding it back in to the list / item again), you should see at the sub-site level that the group also exist with the permission level "Limited Access", meaning it has access to at least 1 unique permission item somewhere within the site.
Edit: This definitely occurs in 2010, but maybe 'hidden' in 2013-2016

Comment: It's the same in 2013, and i would bet it is left unchanged in 2016.

Comment: @Bret but when i add the group inside the list item it will NOT get added inside the list or inside the sub-site. similar if i add the group to the list it will not get added to the sub-site or to the list item/s. similarly if i add the group to the sub-site it will not get added to the list or to its items. so i am not sure how you find that adding the group to the list item will added automatically to the sub-site or to the list with "Limited Access"?? atleast on my end this is not happening (i am using sharepoint farm 2013 on-premises)

Comment: @Christoffer you mean the case i am facing is the supported scenario in sharepoint ?? if the answer is Yes then seems it is really confusing .. as adding the group to the sub-site will not add it to the list nor to the items... but removing the group from the sub-site will remove it from the list and from the list items.. although the sub-site,list and list items in my case have unique permission...so why it is provided this way ?